# What is the purpose of *.ngsummary.json

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli, angular-compiler

I've just learning about `AOT`, `ngc` etc. After running `ngc` I see plenty of `*.ngsummary.json` (in `src` folder, next to `*.ts` files).

What are they for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently the new name of NgFactory files used by the AOT compiler. Search for NgFactory on this page [Ahead-of-Time Compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

Extract :

> After ngc completes, look for a collection of NgFactory files in the aot folder. The aot folder is the directory specified as genDir in tsconfig-aot.json.
>
> These factory files are essential to the compiled application. Each component factory creates an instance of the component at runtime by combining the original class file and a JavaScript representation of the component's template. Note that the original component class is still referenced internally by the generated factory.